# Why does my plane roll so hard?

Tags: microsoft-flight-simulator

I started playing Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 and I’ve managed most of the basics now, but there’s still one major problem I’m dealing with.

No matter what settings I have my plane will have a massive tendency to roll right. I thought this might be an issue with the rudders, but the plane is rolling - not yawing. Trim and flaps seem to be normal too.

I’ve done my best to factor other common issues - I have this issue with assists both turned on and off. This affects both propeller planes and jet planes - and the spin of propellers gives them a tendency to roll left anyway.

The only things I think could account for it is an issue with my controller, which I feel I can factor out after the issue persisted on a second controller; or possibly an issue with which fuel tank my plane is operating from, but the roll is so severe I don’t think that’s it either.

What might be causing my plane to roll hard?

Comment: What if you play with keyboard (no controller), does it still roll?

Comment: I haven’t tried that because it can be really tough to play on keyboard. Things like rudder control can’t be changed gradually. For the purposes of troubleshooting I’ll need some time to learn flying on keyboard and get back to you later

Comment: Which plane are you experiencing this issue with?

Comment: You could get yourself up into the air with the controller then disconnect it.

Comment: @Unionhawk So far, every plane I’ve tried. Cessna 152, Boeing 747, and Cessna Citation CJ4. It really doesn’t narrow the issue down haha. Could be the key binds, game settings, assists, or controller

Comment: @PausePause That actually narrows down the issue quite a bit because now we know it isn't an issue with the flight dynamics of any one particular aircraft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there were two issues I needed to address to fix the tendency to roll the plane. Firstly, I had some form of auto assist enabled which would engage the rudder of my plane but never disengage it. I don't know which assist may have caused it to never disengage, but the rudder would be locked, giving the plane a perpetual yaw, and thus a slight tendency to roll, unless I manually overrode the rudder with my plane's pedals. I suspect it's an issue with takeoff assist trying to keep my plane on the center line, but I'm not completely sure. I disabled nearly all assists and my rate of rolling decreased.

The other, larger issue was the dead zone on my two controllers. Both controllers I was using to operate the plane had a slightly stuck thumbstick which would always pitch the nose down and roll the plane to the right. I had ruled out the controllers because they both had the same result, but they were actually both broken in a similar way. Increasing the dead zone on my sensitivity options to about 8% fixed the issue for me fully.